# Laravel 4 Auth::attempt($userdata, false) authentication is still kept

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, remember-me

Recently I have decided to add a "remember me" feature to my Laravel 4 app.
Appropriate method with syntaxis was found:

```
Auth::attempt(array $credentials = array(), $remember = false)
```

This was adopted for my needs like so:

```
Auth::attempt($userdata, Input::has('remember'))
```

Application kept the Auth session, and the user was authenticated even after browser was closed.

Although, I have found out that now Laravel always keeps a user authenticated, no matter what state "remember" checkmark is.

I have tried to do:

```
Auth::attempt($userdata, false)
```

and

```
Auth::attempt($userdata,)
```

User was still authenticated across the browser sessions!!!
Now, since `Auth::attempt($userdata)` not keeping the auth session, I felt that whenever there is an indications of the second argument in `Auth::attempt` method, Laravel auto assumes it as "true".
Can anyone clarify that?

EDIT:
To make it a super clear to everyone, I will list the steps to recreate this behaviour:

1. Logout of the app `Auth::logout();`
2. Login again `Auth::attempt($userdata, false)`
3. Close and open the browser
4. Go to the app url.
5. Application is loaded authenticated

> *This is my first question here, so please, be patient with me :)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT : OP made clear he called `Auth::logout()` properly, so answer is edited to include the "Real" answer.***

Set `lifetime` value in `app/config/session/php` to `0` to make cookie clear on browser close.

***Previous answer***

This is the `login` method in `Illuminate\Auth\Guard` (Which is facaded to `Auth`) class, which is eventually called by `Auth::attempt()`.

source : http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Auth.Guard.html#263-291

```
 public function login(UserInterface $user, $remember = false)
 {
     $id = $user->getAuthIdentifier();

     $this->session->put($this->getName(), $id);

     // If the user should be permanently "remembered" by the application we will
     // queue a permanent cookie that contains the encrypted copy of the user
     // identifier. We will then decrypt this later to retrieve the users.
     if ($remember)
     {
         $this->queuedCookies[] = $this->createRecaller($id);
     }

     // If we have an event dispatcher instance set we will fire an event so that
     // any listeners will hook into the authentication events and run actions
     // based on the login and logout events fired from the guard instances.
     if (isset($this->events))
     {
         $this->events->fire('auth.login', array($user, $remember));
     }

     $this->setUser($user);
 }
```

It is clear that even though the cookie is set when `$remember` is set to `true`, the cookie itself is not cleared when `$remember` is set to false or other non-truthy value.

The cookie is cleared when you call `Auth::logout()` function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I just not sure what you mean - I am talking about "clean" login, without any cookie set before hand.

Comment: Have you called `logout()` after previous login?

Comment: What is the value in `lifetime` in `app/config/session.php`? You have to set it to `0`, if you want to clear cookies when browser closes.

Comment: Right on the spot! I have set it to be 120 long time ago, and forgot all about it! Now everything is fine! THANK YOU! Can you edit your answer to include the solution, in case someone else with same problem would come searching? :)

Comment: Setting `lifetime` to `0` messed with other session-based features in my app, like validation errors passed to the view, etc. Be careful when you use it, I think a lifetime of 60 minutes (when the user doesn't want to be remembered, or didn't tick the "remember me" checkbox) is about right. I don't know in which version it was implemented, but there is the `expire_on_close` parameter that should do what we want, just below `lifetime`.